Unity Cloud - SDK does not contain 'libarclite'
I am trying to automate IOS build with unity could but every time I get this error:
[error] 7.5.2.2.7.4 - INFO: ❌  clang: error: SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path '/APPLICATION_PATH/Xcode15_2_0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a'; try increasing the minimum deployment target
I have set the target to 14.0 in the player settings. I tried setting xcode and unity versions to higher or lower (I work with xcode 15 and unity 2022.5f) but nothing seems to work. Build always fails like this:
error] - 7.5.2.2.7.4 - ERROR: xcode build failed 
[error]   RuntimeError (Build Failure):
[error] /BUILD_PATH/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/bvr-7.5.2.2.7.4/lib/bvr/build/handlers/platform/xcode_compiler.rb:319:in `block in exec_fastlane': Build Failure (RuntimeError)

All threads I have found are on changing the xcode settings but I have no idea how would I do it with the cloud build.

Does this help?
